# Eclipse custom text editor update syntax highlighting

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am writing an Eclipse plugin (Indigo/Juno) that contains a text editor for a custom text format. I am following the tutorial here: http://www.realsolve.co.uk/site/tech/jface-text.php

So far I have everything working. Eclipse will use my editor to edit files. I have partitioning, damaging, repairing, syntax highlighting all working.

I added a preferences page with color pickers to control syntax highlighting. It works mostly correct. If I update the colors, the editor uses them the next time I open or reopen a file.

How do I get an editor tab to update itself without opening a new one? The built-in JDT Java editor does this, but so far I have not been able to decipher how (it is a very large and complex editor).

I gather that I need to create a preferences listener (http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePreferences/article.html). I have done this and can verify that my listener code is being invoked when I set a breakpoint in it.

The missing piece is the wiring between the listener and reinitializing the editor. I have tried reconstructing the partitioning logic, the color logic, the damager/repairer, etc. but nothing seems to work. It either does nothing I can see or at worst will corrupt the display until I scroll the current text out of view to repaint it... with the old colors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `SourceViewer.invalidatePresentation()` needs to be called.

Comment: That is part of it, but the answer is incomplete. First, I had to remove and reinstall the damagers and repairers since they know how to format the text. Then I had to invalidate the presentation to force the view to update.

Comment: @Snowman Can you write your own answer with a more complete description? (I am also trying to get this to work in my plug-in)

Comment: @Eyal I have since moved on from that place of employment and no longer have access to that code. I will try to dig this up from memory though, I realize that I left this question unanswered.

Comment: projectionViewer.invalidateTextPresentation();
  try {
   editor.getDocumentProvider().resetDocument((editor.getEditorInput()));
  } catch (CoreException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Answer (score 0):

It may be already late to you, but if you want you could use LiClipse for that (http://brainwy.github.io/liclipse/) -- one of its targets is easily doing an editor with syntax highlighting, basic code-completion, outline, etc targeting Eclipse.

No java skills are required to add a new language (mostly creating a new .liclipse -- which is a YAML -- file in the proper place and creating some basic rules to say how to partition your language -- i.e.: usually just separating code from comments from strings -- and specifying the keywords you have in the partition would already give you proper syntax highlighting).

If you download it, there are a number of examples at plugins\com.brainwy.liclipse.editor\languages and there's some basic documentation at http://brainwy.github.io/liclipse/supported_languages.html and http://brainwy.github.io/liclipse/scope_definition.html on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this as I did:
    My solution involved adding the following lines into the Constructor of my Editor

```java
Activator.getActivator().getPreferenceStore().addPropertyChangeListener(new IPropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
                getSourceViewer().invalidateTextPresentation();
                handlePreferenceStoreChanged(event);
            }
        });
```

and then creating a custom class that extended IToken. In the constructor I pass the String of the preference field and then in the 'getObject' method I create the TextAttribute: snippets below

```java
public class MyToken extends Token implements IToken {

    public MyToken(Object data) {
        super(data);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getData() {
        String dataString = (String) super.getData();
        return getAttributeFromColorName(dataString);
    }

    private TextAttribute getAttributeFromColorName(String preferenceField) {
        Color color =  new Color(Display.getCurrent(), StringConverter.asRGB(Activator.getActivator().getPreferenceStore().getString(preferenceField)));
        return new TextAttribute(color);
    }

}
```

When I generate my Rules I have all of my tokens as my custom class and this allowed me to change syntax color dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I also added an example for updating the coloring if the preference changes to https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseEditors/article.html#exercise-allow-user-to-customize-the-colors

This is using the Generic editor (currently the best approach to implement a customer editor) but it should be possible to adjust this to any Eclipse editor implementation.